# JasperReport Excel export cuts content after wordwrap (Stretch with overflow)

Tags: jasper-reports, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am having Jasper Report API 5.0.1. I have a report having sub report to export data in excel format.

When I export report in excel, some overflowed content of cell slightly cuts down and not able to view until we resize row height. Here is the snapshot of how it looks.

[image]

I have checked for solution on Stackoverflow and Jasper report community forum and tried solutions suggested in there. But none have worked for me.

I tried:

- `net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text` to `true`
- Set `Stretch Type` of all band elements to `Relative to Band Height`

But none of the options worked for me.

Can anyone please point out where I might be doing wrong?

If there is a solution with Apache POI then I am open to apply it, if it fixes the issue.

**Update with code and jasper report:**

jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MemberWorkListing_subreport" pageWidth="750" pageHeight="802" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="750" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="50014970-029e-488c-9e4b-b42b8d743e84">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM TMP_WK_DTL]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="WK_INT_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="WID_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ISWC_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TTL_ENG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TTL_LOCAL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DURATION" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="WK_LG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="WK_CAT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="WK_STATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ART_NAME_EL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ART_NAME_LE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IP_SET_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="IP_INT_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="IP_NAMETYPE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IP_WK_ROLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IP_NAME_ENG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IP_NAME_LOCAL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SOC_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PER_OWN_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="PER_COLL_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="MEC_OWN_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="MEC_COLL_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SYN_OWN_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SYN_COLL_SHR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SEQ" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="AGR_NO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="workCount" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="internalNoGroup">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{workCount} + 1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="internalNoGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{WK_INT_NO}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="34">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6bca70f4-3fc8-42b9-bc88-0b491f747c97" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ INTERNAL NO]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e20675cf-ac73-4baa-95cd-a4ff4a8365c8" mode="Opaque" x="80" y="0" width="70" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ISWC NO]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c23427f6-11da-4b52-a7dd-df63116c8f6f" mode="Opaque" x="150" y="0" width="180" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TITLE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9cd3477c-5763-40fe-9565-0dd412830fc2" mode="Opaque" x="330" y="0" width="80" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[LANGUAGE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9863dbce-c990-44b7-b56c-fa8f3bbb0a00" mode="Opaque" x="410" y="0" width="80" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CATEGORY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3baef4d4-aaf6-4024-9ebd-d47bdf348871" mode="Opaque" x="490" y="0" width="80" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[STATUS]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="72f3706d-885b-4a44-9608-bea5afe6186e" mode="Opaque" x="570" y="0" width="180" height="34" backcolor="#C0C0C0"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ARTISTE]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="660806ed-1806-4020-9a0f-c14408440422" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WK_INT_NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ad71b230-bfa8-480e-93c1-ccc6e48f57c5" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="80" y="0" width="70" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ISWC_NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="eec7d04e-6f4c-4b28-a3fe-8a3433339d14" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="150" y="0" width="180" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TTL_ENG}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="d53915b9-edb6-439d-bec5-fd6231043a37" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="330" y="0" width="80" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WK_LG}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="30e29311-5da3-481f-bb34-d78e4b5b7510" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="410" y="0" width="80" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WK_CAT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="375efa25-af3b-4699-9a75-56998b52b62e" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="490" y="0" width="80" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WK_STATUS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ee80e636-4a4c-4fbf-90c0-fc61d8c0b894" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="570" y="0" width="180" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial Narrow"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ART_NAME_EL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Export code:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlfile, jasperfile);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperfile, reportParameter, dbConnection);

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, reportFile);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS,Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);

exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Comment: Please add an [mcve] that we can test (jrxml+code you use to export), the simpler the better, otherwise we need to setup our own tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly export to Excel, you should prepare your reports following [the guidelines - Making HTML, XLS or CSV friendly reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/making-html-xls-or-csv-friendly-reports)

The issue is that some of the elements composing your report are a bit overlapping or not properly aligned.